# How to update column values in place without creating a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[Existing dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLpye.png)

How to get the desired output as shown below using pandas?

[Desired dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEZMc.png)

Columns A,B,C,D are existing quantity. 
Columns A1,B1,C1,D1 are shortage quantities.
How to redistribute the existing quantities to the columns in shortage quantities? 
The existing quantities should be redistributed in the order of C,B,A,D. 
For example, if A1 requires 10 quantity, first it should take values from 'C' and once it becomes zero it should take column 'B' values. Once all the values of A,B,C,D becomes zero, the remaining value should be added in a new column 'Remaining'. 
Pls help to sort this out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## Easy Way

I think it will do the job. The issue with your need is that it is not easy to maintain. What will be the order of columns 'E' if one day you need a new column ?

```
df['shortage'] = df.A1 + df.B1 + df.C1 + df.D1

df['remaining'] = df['shortage'] - df.D - df.C - df.B - df.A
df.loc[df.remaining < 0, 'remaining'] = 0

df.C = df.C - df['shortage']
df.loc[df.C < 0, 'C'] = 0

df.B = df.C + df.B - df['shortage']
df.loc[df.B < 0, 'B'] = 0

df.A = df.C + df.B + df.A - df['shortage']
df.loc[df.A < 0, 'A'] = 0

df.D = df.C + df.B + df.A + df.D - df['shortage']
df.loc[df.D < 0, 'D'] = 0

for col in ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1']:
    df.loc[df[col] != 0, col] = df.loc[df[col] != 0, 'remaining']

df = df.drop('shortage', axis=1)
```

## Dynamic way

As the code above is not dynamic, I give you a second way below that allows you to have new columns (e.g. column 'E')
The only thing you have to maintain is the order line 1

```
order = ['C', 'B', 'A', 'D']

# get the list of shortage_col (those which starts with 1) and non_shortage_col (the others)
shortage_col = [col for col in df.columns.tolist() if col.endswith('1')]
non_shortage_col = [col for col in df.columns.tolist() if not (col.endswith('1') | (col == 'Item'))]

# add together all columns that are in shortage_col
df['shortage'] = np.sum(df[shortage_col].values.tolist(),axis=1)

df['remaining'] = df['shortage'] - np.sum(df[non_shortage_col].values.tolist(),axis=1)
df.loc[df.remaining < 0, 'remaining'] = 0

# loop through order to get the list of all previous values for each item in order
# returns a list like that [['C'], ['C', 'B'], ['C', 'B', 'A'], ['C', 'B', 'A', 'D']]
to_add = []
for i in range(len(order)):
    list_of_previous = []
    for index, element in enumerate(order):
        if index < i + 1:
            list_of_previous.append(element)
    to_add.append(list_of_previous)

for i in range(len(order)):
    col = order[i]
    # same as : df.D = df.C + df.B + df.A + df.D - df['shortage']
    df[col] = np.sum(df[to_add[i]].values.tolist(),axis=1) - df['shortage']
    # same as : df.loc[df.D < 0, 'D'] = 0
    df.loc[df[col] < 0, col] = 0

for col in ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1']:
    df.loc[df[col] != 0, col] = df.loc[df[col] != 0, 'remaining']

df = df.drop('shortage', axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks Charles R.

Comment: But the values in the columns A1,B1,C1,D1 doesn't get updated while the values in columns A,B,C,D are correctly updated. Adding one more condition,the order for column A1 is ['C', 'B', 'A', 'D'], for B1 it is ['B', 'C', 'A', 'D'], for C1 it is ['A', 'D', 'C', 'B'] and for D1 it is ['D', 'B', 'A', 'C']. Pls help to sort out this.

Comment: I don't understand your point. Both methods give you the output that you linked to your topic. If your expected output have changed, could you please update it and tell me when its done ?